# How to get copy of the older version of the file from CVS

Tags: cvs

I have CVS used in my company.
I would like to stay on the current version for the file, but retrieve copy of the older version into different file name.

I have current revision 1.136, but I need to get revision 1.130.

```
head: 1.136
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 136;   selected revisions: 136
```

Comment: What version of offive you are using. please provide more detial on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to

- retrieve the old version
- rename it to a different name
- restore the current version

It should be possible to do it with something like:

```
cvs checkout -D 2010-05-01 directory/file1 #Use  the  most  recent  revision  no later than 2010-05-01
cp directory/file1 myNewFile.txt
cvs update -C directory/file1
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got it slightly different way:

```
cvs up -r1.130 myfile.txt
cp myfile.txt myfile.txt.v1.130
cvs up -r1.136 myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from a bash script I wrote:

```
module="$(cat "$SOURCE_DIR/CVS/Repository")"
cvs -Q co -r "$rev" -p "$module/$pathname" > "$pathname"
```

The name of the module is stored in the `Repository` file within the `CVS` folder.

A breakdown of the cvs options:

| Option | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| -Q | Don't print anything but the content of the file. |
| co | Short version of `checkout`. |
| -r | Specify revision number. |
| $rev | The revision number. |
| -p | Print the file to `stdout`. |
| $module/$pathname | The file to be retrieved. |